# Call to a member function result() on boolean error after switching to sqlsrv dbdriver

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

everything works fine except for triggering an Stored procedure from my model and starts showing an Call to a member function result() on boolean error line.

Here is an example of code without using an SP it works fine.

```
function get_myeligible_info($id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM emp_list_manila where employee_empid = '".$id."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

and here is the exact code that shows an error.

```
function get_for_batch_insert2()
{

$query = $this->db->query("[INSERT_TTUMBATCH]");
return $query->result(); //ERROR HERE

}
```

**Web application framework**: Codeigniter 3 **Database**: MS SQL

Comment: What does the stored procedure do? Does it return a result set?

Comment: Yes, it select a data from a table and insert at the same time.

Comment: You may need to consider using `SET NOCOUNT ON;` then at the start of your stored procedure. This will prevent the insert being processed as a result set (that returns no rows). There are other ways to get around this, but I imagine this is probably what is causing your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, NEVER put variables directly into a query. Always use [parameter binding](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings) like this:

```
function get_myeligible_info($id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM emp_list_manila WHERE employee_empid = ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, [$id]);
    return $query->result();
}
```

For stored procedures, you can't just call them by name, [you have to use `EXEC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/execute-a-stored-procedure):

```
function get_for_batch_insert2()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("EXEC INSERT_TTUMBATCH");
    return $query->result();
}
```

For both these calls, you should be checking for errors and dealing with them appropriately:

```
function get_for_batch_insert2()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("EXEC INSERT_TTUMBATCH");
    if ($query) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now, noted with not putting the variables in query.